# Como fazer uma atualização frequente

Tags: php, html, atualização

Olá, por exemplo, eu tenho a caixa de texto `SENHA` e `CONFIRMARSENHA`, e testo se elas são diferentes, porém só vou saber quando ele apertar um botão, e eu quero que no momento que elas sejam diferentes (sem precisar apertar o botão) eu já saiba disso.

Grato desde já.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para isso você vai precisar utilizar javascript para verificar se o valor dos campos está igual no momento que for preenchido o campo de confirmação. O nome desse evento é `onBlur`.

A implementação seria nessa ideia:

O HTML e o Javascript:

```html
    <form id="formulario">
        <input type="password" id="senha"> Senha <br/>
        <input type="password" id="confirma_senha" onBlur="verificaIgual()"> Confirma Senha <br/>
    </form>
```

```js
        function verificaIgual(){
            var senha = document.getElementById('senha');
            var confirma = document.getElementById('confirma_senha');
    
            if(senha.value != confirma.value){
                alert("As senhas devem ser iguais");
            }
    
        }
```